# Matrix gradient of linear form

Tags: matrix-calculus

My question is very basic, and I ask it because I haven't seem to have found it online. What is the matrix gradient (with respect to A) of Ax, where A is m by n and x is n by 1?

Comment: The answers to this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638170/vector-by-matrix-derivitive) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\bf E}$ represent the 4th order tensor
$$\eqalign{
  {\bf E} &= \frac {\partial A} {\partial A} \cr 
  {\bf E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}  \cr
}$$
Then the derivative of $f=A x$ is a 3rd order tensor, which can be written as 
$$\eqalign{
  \frac {\partial f} {\partial A} &= {\bf E}\,x \cr
  \frac {\partial f_i} {\partial A_{kl}} &= \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} x_j \cr
    &= \delta_{ik} \delta_{lj} x_j \cr
}$$